# Login failed for user (but not really) in SSDT in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

I have a weird problem with SSDT(Visual Studio 2017 server explorer) when I try to view the tables in my Database

In SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio 2017) I created a database with a new user called `admin`. This user has `public` and `sysadmin` permissions and can execute CRUD queries and see the tables in the Object Explorer. [image: As shown in this SSMS view image]

So everything is working fine... However, when I try to connect to the database from VS2017 with SSDT I succeed to connect to the server, but I cant view the tables inside the `Server Explorer` and it throws me the `"Login Failed for user..."` error. However when I try the same with the `SQL Server Object Explorer` it works fine: [image: like shown here]

Why do i get this error? The credentials are correct otherwise it wouldn't have worked in SSMS and object explorer. My permissions are correct otherwise I wouldn't have been able to create the table and insert data into it. Why do I get the Login failed error in the `Server Explorer`?

Comment: check SQL Server error log for this error. The reason of failure is written there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I managed to fix the "problem",

I was entering the correct credentials, but it was still giving me this error. 
So what i tried this time is to eneabled the `Save my password` checkbox.... and it worked...

I deleted the connection and created a new connection (without checking the `Save my password`) and again the same error. So i enabled the checkbox again and it worked...

I think when trying to reach for the tables it re-authenticates at the SQL server, and since the checkbox `Save my password` was not enabled, it didnt have a password to authenticate with.

Answer (score 0):

check your credentials in the properties of the connection

[image]